# Resources for combining traditional and mobile ASP.NET web development

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website, code-reuse

As a developer of a traditional ASP.NET web application (non-MVC) who is getting requests for a mobile-friendly version, I'm wondering where I might find some wisdom about the best way to approach the problem.  We currently mask most of our database access through web service calls.

It seems like many shops would find themselves in this situation: We have limited resources and don't wish to create a maintenance headache by having versions of an application diverge greatly.

Is there a set of best practices for taking an existing System.Web application and reorganizing code in order to accommodate adding mobile-friendliness.  The general approach I'm thinking of is:

1. Make small stylistic changes on the
   client using CSS or even JavaScript.
2. Make any necessary changes in data,
   workflow, or markup in server-side
   code.
3. Keep as much code as possible common
   to the two versions by organizing
   non-UI logic into separate
   assemblies.  Conditional compilation
   would be used in code-behind where
   UIs must diverge.

What are the gotchas that I'll run into with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short and sweet:**

- Read the [W3C Mobile Web Application Best Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/)
- Separate your business/application logic and presentation logic as much as possible
- Do server-side detection of mobile devices; serve an *extremely* simplified UI to mobile devices
- Use client-side techniques like CSS media queries and feature detection (such as that done with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com)) to do progressive enhancement

**The long version:**

The most important thing to remember is that as similar as they appear, the mobile web and desktop web ARE different.  The analogy I use the difference between a street and a sidewalk.  Both of them are made for generally the same purpose - to get people from one location to another.  However, they were designed separately and are intended for use by different modes of transport.  You can drive a car on the sidewalk, and you can walk in the middle of the street, but neither experience will be optimal.

Long story short, for a good mobile site, you must design *specifically* for a mobile device.  This doesn't mean you can't reuse logic - you definitely should.  I'm just saying that using JavaScript/CSS to hide a few elements does not turn a regular site into a mobile site.

For what it's worth, I recently gave a presentation with one of my colleagues on mobile web development strategies.  It is mostly targeted towards mobile web in higher education (college campuses) and my campus (UCSB), but many of the strategies and techniques are widely applicable.  Interested parties can find the presentation and related resources here: https://it.ucsb.edu/groups/wsg/mobile-web-brown-bag

**Resources**

Server-Side Device Detection:

- [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/)
- [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
- [51Degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/)

Client-Side Feature Support Detection / Progressive Enhancement:

- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com)
- [EnhanceJS](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/introducing_enhancejs_smarter_safer_apply_progressive_enhancement/)

Random Resources

- [Mobile Web Resources](http://www.diigo.com/user/joesabado/mobileweb) (My colleague's reading list)
- [W3C Mobile Web Application Best Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/)

Comment: Excellent resources.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

First, these days mobile doesn't necessarily mean doing the things that System.Web.Mobile come, but rather supporting the mobile use case and the limitations of mobile devices. Or, you want to strip down your app to be relevent to mobile users, and you want to do things like limit bandwidth required, browser plugins, heavy scripting and screen size required. But you actually don't need to go back to the bad old days of WAP and such.

Comment: Okay, this was news to me.  As you indicated and the article at http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application states: "System.Web.Mobile.dll ... is still included in ASP.NET 4, but it is deprecated.  The reason ... is that ... the controls are mainly designed to render WML or cHTML markup (instead of regular HTML) for the WAP browsers of that era."  In light of this, I'm modifying my question.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading the way forward seems to be to design for mobile first and then customise the layout using @media CSS to introduce more design/functionality concepts in more capable devices.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://www.slideshare.net/arborwebsolutions/practical-beyond-responsive-web-design

Comment: That might be true in an ideal world, but I'm talking about an application that is in place and which I can't completely rewrite.